# PyYAML Object return to dictionary

Tags: python, pyyaml

I am new to python and I want to parse the config.yaml below

```
name: bank_csv_sample_yaml
description: "This yaml will export csv file to another csv file"

initialize:
  - !DataSource
    name: bank_source
    description: "Source details"
    dfid: bank_dataframe
    type: flatfile
    location: 
    filename: "bank1.csv"
    format: csv
```

Here's my code for python

```
import yaml

class DataSource(yaml.YAMLObject):
    yaml_tag = '!DataSource'

    def __init__(self, name, description, dfid, type, location, filename, format):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.dfid = dfid
        self.type = type
        self.location = location
        self.filename = filename
        self.format = format

    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s(name:%r, description:%r, dfid:%r, type:%r, location:%r, filename:%r, format:%r)" % (self.__class__.__name__, self.name, self.description, self.dfid, self.type, self.location, self.filename, self.format)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("config.yaml", "r") as yaml_reader:
        yaml_data = yaml.load(yaml_reader, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
        print(yaml_data)
```

And got the result

```
{'name': 'bank_csv_sample_yaml', 'description': 'This yaml will export csv file to another csv file', 'initialize': [DataSource(name:'bank_source', description:'Source details', dfid:'bank_dataframe', type:'flatfile', location:None, filename:'bank1.csv', format:'csv')]}
```

How am I able to convert

```
[DataSource(name:'bank_source', description:'Source details', dfid:'bank_dataframe', type:'flatfile', location:None, filename:'bank1.csv', format:'csv')]
```

into a dictionary? I don't know how to split these values.

Expected output is something like this a nested dictionary.

```
{'name': 'bank_csv_sample_yaml', 'description': 'This yaml will export csv file to another csv file', 'initialize': {‘DataSource’ : {name: 'bank_source', description: 'Source details', dfid: 'bank_dataframe', type: 'flatfile', location: None, filename: 'bank1.csv', format: 'csv'}}}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you mention clearly what is your expected output ?

Comment: Something like this  {'name': 'bank_csv_sample_yaml', 'description': 'This yaml will export csv file to another csv file', 'initialize': {DataSource : {name: 'bank_source', description: 'Source details', dfid: 'bank_dataframe', type: 'flatfile', location: None, filename: 'bank1.csv', format: 'csv'}}} . Is it possible?

Comment: I think you'll have to define a representer. You'll find examples in the doc https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#constructors-representers-resolvers